# How to make a C++ program that factors a quadratic expression into the form (x + a)(x + b)

Tags: c++

I have the code for a program (in C++) that intends to completely factor a quadratic equation completely, but it isn't really working.

My approach is to use a method called **decomposition**, which states that in the equation

> x² + bx + c

where *x* is a variable and *b* and *c* are integers, this equation is equal to

> (x + *d*)(x + *e*)

where *d* and *e* are numbers that add to *b* and multiply to *c*.

Currently, this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cout << "Enter the parts of an equation and we will factorise it for you" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "        2" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter x  :" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter x" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "Enter the other number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> c;

    int d = rand() % RAND_MAX + 1;
    int e = rand() % RAND_MAX + 1; 
    if (a = 1) {
        if (d + e == b, d * e == c) {
            std::cout << "The factorised form of your equation is:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "(x + " << d << ")(x + " << e << std::endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to look for another way of finding the values of d and e, since generating two random integer and checking for their sums and products doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You can write `d`and `e` as expressions involving `b` and `c`. Take out your old maths book.

Comment: Also, `d + e == b, d * e == c` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: `-d` and `-e` are the solution of the quadratic equation.

Comment: This is not not so much a programming problem than a math problem. You don't, even as a human, randomly *guess* the answer, your program shouldn't either.

Comment: So you basically take two random numbers and check if they satisfy your equation? This is a very very bad approach!

Comment: `if (a = 1) {` just sets a to 1 and then always takes this branch. This is a minor quibble since everything else is broken anyway - you should really figure out the algorithm first and then worry about coding it.

Comment: You probably didn't mean to *assign* to `a` in `if (a = 1)` - that's such a common mistake that most compilers will warn you about it (assuming you've enabled the warnings).

Answer (score 0):

since the equation you post is from 2nd degree polynomial equ., you can calculate the zeros
[image]

now using the equation:[image]

you will find 2 variables, x1 and x2.

the result is:

your funcition can be factorized as **(x-x1)*(x-x2)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the well-known formula for finding the roots of `ax²+bx+c=0`, namely `x = (-b ± sqrt(b² - 4ac)) / 2a` to get a formula for the roots you need.  Note that you will need to either use complex numbers or report that the expression can't be factorized if there are no real roots.

```
double discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (discriminant < 0) {
    std::cout << "This expression cannot be factorized to real factors" << std::endl;
} else {
    double drt = sqrt(discriminant); 
    double d = (-b - drt) / 2 / a;
    double e = (-b + drt) / 2 / a;
    std::cout << a << "(x - " << d << ")(x - " << e << ")" << std::endl;
}
```